Whenever I try to install anything by pip, I get module No module named certifi
I have python 3.11 in a conda environment which I have been using for a while now, problem free.  Just today, I have noticed that when I install anything with pip, including pip install certifi I get

No module named certifi

What could have gone wrong?  Here is my stack trace:
>   File
> "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\py311\Lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py",
> line 24, in <module>
>     sys.exit(_main())
>              ^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\py311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py",
> line 78, in main
>     command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
>               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File
> "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\py311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py",
> line 114, in create_command
>     module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
>              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\py311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py",
> line 126, in import_module
>     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import   File
> "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load   File
> "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked  
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in
> exec_module   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in
> _call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\py311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py",
> line 16, in <module>
>     from pip._internal.cli.req_command import (   File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\py311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py",
> line 18, in <module>
>     from pip._internal.index.collector import LinkCollector   File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\py311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py",
> line 31, in <module>
>     from pip._vendor import requests   File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\py311\Lib\site-packages\wrapt\importer.py",
> line 184, in _self_exec_module
>     self.__wrapped__.exec_module(module)   File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\py311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py",
> line 146, in <module>
>     from . import packages, utils   File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\py311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py",
> line 24, in <module>
>     from . import certs   File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\py311\Lib\site-packages\wrapt\importer.py",
> line 185, in _self_exec_module
>     notify_module_loaded(module)   File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\py311\Lib\site-packages\wrapt\importer.py",
> line 118, in notify_module_loaded
>     hook(module)   File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\py311\Lib\site-packages\certifi_win32\wrapt_pip.py",
> line 35, in apply_patches
>     import certifi ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'certifi'


So I mean one thing I can probably do is create a new conda environment, but I would like to know what might have gone wrong with the environment I was using.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78812490/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%22No+module+named+certifi%22

@phd Yeah sounds like it, a likely culprit.  certifi was likely uninstalled.  A pain to get thing s back.

Manually. Or recreate the entire virtual env. Alas!
